# Duda de mailchimp y nztim/mailchimp

Tags: laravel, formularios

Estoy tratando de usar mailchimp en Laravel y un repositorio de github para facilitarlo. Pero cuando mando el formulario me aparece el siguiente error:

> Non-static method NZTim\Mailchimp\Mailchimp::check() should not be
>   called statically

```
    public function correo(Request $request){
    $listId= '00000000';
    $emailAddress=$request->input('email');
    if(Mailchimp::check($listId, $emailAddress))
    return view('existente');
    else
    return 'no existe';
}
```

El repositorio es:
https://github.com/nztim/mailchimp

Answer (score 1):

Tengo el mismo error, lo que hice fue

```
protected $mailchimp;

public function __construct() {
   try {
      $this->mailchimp = new Mailchimp(env('MC_KEY'));
   } 
   catch (MailchimpException $e) {
   }
}

public function index() {
   $lists = $this->mailchimp->check();
}
```